# How to determine the center zip code for each state?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Zip Code MySQL database that has the lat/lng of each zip code. How do I go about finding the center zip code for each state? I would be doing this in PHP.

Comment: @Brad: [Geographical centre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_center) is a well-defined property (being the radial projection of a [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) onto the Earth's surface); see also [Geographic centres of the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_centers_of_the_United_States).

Comment: @eggyal, It's not so well-defined as you might think.  Who's to say he wants geographical center?  This is particularly problematic for cities.  What's the center zip code?  Some of the zip code boundaries are very irregular.  Do you just want the hit on the zip code that the center point is within?  What if that zip code has multiple boundaries and only a small portion is at that point?  Maybe you want the zip code whose center point is closest to the center point of the state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kludge it. Make all the states rectangles.

```
SELECT
  state,
  (MAX(lat)-MIN(lat))/2 + MIN(lat) 'center_lat',
  (MAX(lng)-MIN(lng))/2 + MIN(lng) 'center_lng'
FROM table
GROUP BY state
```

It's not perfect, but unless you like complex math it's the best of a bad situation.

*edit*: I just re-read the question, realized it's not asking for the center lat/lng, but center zip. Having retrieved a list of the approximate center lat/lng for each state you can loop through and find the nearest ZIP to each.

```
SELECT
  zip,
  ABS(lat-$center_lat) + ABS(lng-$center_lng) 'diff'
FROM table
WHERE state = $state
ORDER BY diff ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: With an oddly shaped state, you could end up with coordinates for a "centre" which are in an altogether different state.  For example, take Idaho: `center_lat` will be quite far north: the resulting centre point could be in Montana; Florida's midpoint will almost certainly be in the Atlantic Ocean; etc.  Then locating the "closest" ZIP code in this fashion ignores the fact that lines of longitude get closer together as you approach the poles (and further apart toward the equator).  I agree that this is a cheap-and-easy approach, but sadly I fear it may be too crude to be of any practical use.

Comment: Yeah, the 'center' could be outside the actual state, but the second statement would still pick a ZIP still inside the actual state. I said it's a kludge, but I'm not clever enough to come up with a solution like you've posted. :P

Comment: The latest SQL from your edit was most helpful for two states, HI and AK! Because the center lat/lng for those two states we not part of a zip code, so your SQL was able to locate the nearest one! In both cases they were about 20-30 miles away.

I'm still trying to understand how what you did works. Also, what does the 'diff' represent? Thanks!

Comment: `diff` is a just a kudgy, foreshortened method to find the "distance" between two points since the actual value isn't important. It should be really be `SQRT(POW(ABS(lat-$center_lat), 2) + POW(ABS(lng-$center_lng), 2))` for pythagorean whatever. :P

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you wish to treat the coordinates of each zip code as equally weighted points within each state, and find the ZIP code closest to the effective "centre of mass", you can do it directly in MySQL by combining:

- [How to calculate geographical centre](http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html);
- the [Finding Locations with MySQL](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql) section of Google's article on Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps; and
- the general technique for obtaining a [groupwise minimum/maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

The complete query is:

```sql
-- the closest ZIP code
SELECT state, z.zip_code
FROM   zip_codes z JOIN (

  -- the distance between the "centre of mass" and the closest ZIP code
  SELECT   state, c.lat, c.lon
           MIN(ACOS(
             COS(c.lat) * COS(RADIANS(z.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(z.lon) - c.lon)
           + SIN(c.lat) * SIN(RADIANS(z.lat))
           )) min
  FROM     zip_codes z JOIN (

    -- the "centre of mass" of each state
    SELECT   state, 
             ATAN2(
               SUM(SIN(RADIANS(lat))) / COUNT(*),
               SQRT(
                 POW(SUM(COS(RADIANS(lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(lon))) / COUNT(*), 2)
               + POW(SUM(COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lon))) / COUNT(*), 2)
               )
             ) AS lat,
             ATAN2(
               SUM(COS(RADIANS(lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(lon))) / COUNT(*),
               SUM(COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lon))) / COUNT(*)
             ) AS lon
    FROM     zip_codes
    GROUP BY state

  ) c USING (state)
  GROUP BY state

) d USING (state)
WHERE  ACOS(
         COS(d.lat) * COS(RADIANS(z.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(z.lon) - d.lon)
       + SIN(d.lat) * SIN(RADIANS(z.lat))
       ) = d.min
```

#### Notes

1. This could prove pretty slow, as indexing (other than on the `state` column) will not be of much use, but then again it's a one-time only operation so cacheing the result shouldn't prove too much of a problem.
2. There are many ZIP codes in densely populated areas, and few in sparsely populated areas.  As a result, the determined "centre of mass" may be some distance away from the geographical centre (but it could be a reasonable proxy for the population centre, if that's what is desired).

   Adding a suitable weighting to each ZIP code would yield reasonable *approximations*: e.g. weight by the total land area each ZIP code covers to find geographical centre; or by population resident within each ZIP code to find actual population centre.

   The only way to have a *true* geographical centre would be to derive the centroid from each state's borders.  You can download the coordinates of suitable bounding polygons from the [CloudMade Downloads](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/americas/northern_america/united_states#downloads_breadcrumbs) site.